# Simplest and cheapest way to start WPF testing

Tags: wpf, testing, automated-tests

I have a (closed source) WPF application containing mainly two modules: A UI exe and a "Model" dll. One screen (for now) and about 30 classes.

I would like to start testing it with testing tools.

I have resharper.

I don't have time :). I don't want to strat learning about factories, mocking, IOC and so on. And I don't want to disturb the code too much (re IOC etc.)

I don't have alota money. I saw a recommendation here for [SmartBear's TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools) and then I saw its $2K price tag and I balked at the price: at $99 I would weep at pay, and you can't beat free :)

So, my question is: "**What is the simplest and cheapest way for me to start WPF testing, not necessarily the *best* colution but something that will provide some benefit at low cost?**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go to the free route, you can have a look at System.Windows.Automation namespace : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.aspx

See this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483216.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to concentrate on the 30 classes (non GUI) to test. It seems (but I'm not sure) that most functionality is in those 30 classes.

If designed well, the model (those 30 classes) can be tested reasonably easy.
For GUI testing a lot more effort is normally needed.

So if you want to spend less time, concentrate on testing the model.

For testing the model, what you normally do is: write stubs for external components (if needed), set the input parameters (depending on your app) and check if the 'output' is what you expect.

Comment: Good idea, simplifying the problem and avoiding for now testing the UI. How would you suggest I test the model in the simplest and cheapest way?

Answer (score 2):

A free and interesting approach is Approval Tests: http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/. You would essentially "approve" your UI and then execute tests against your app. If the resulting UI doesn't match up with the approved version then the test fails. The comparison here is based on images of your UI - this clearly has pros and cons when compared to other testing approaches.

This video is an example of using Approval Tests with WPF: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc_ty03lZ9U&list=PL0C32F89E8BBB5368&index=17&feature=plpp_video